# I can't set my clan tag in Black Ops 3

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I am having trouble setting a clan tag. I don't have an internet connection on my PS4, so I just play offline on a LAN. After I type type the clan tag in it just disappears when I exit the menu, as if I never entered it. Other PS4 accounts can create clan tags, just not mine.

Comment: Parental controls are surely not the problem.

Comment: Note it works fine while the menu is still up

Comment: Are you entering a valid tag? It will not stick if the tag violates any of Treyarch's rules (language, character types, symbols, etc)